# forming pairs of non-contiguous elements from an array

Tags: python, numpy

There are multiple examples of generator expressions yielding pairs of contiguous elements from a list on this website. However, I'd like to do something a little different:

given `np.arange(6)`, I would like to output `[[0, 3], [1, 4], [2, 5]]` (here, in the form of a list, but both `list` and `np.ndarray` output formats would be ok).

Of course, I could do that with `for` loops and quick-and-dirty `numpy` indexing, but is there a more elegant (and hopefully faster) way of doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) while specifying Fortran order (first index changes the fastest):

```
In [104]: np.arange(6).reshape(3, -1, order='F')
Out[104]: 
array([[0, 3],
       [1, 4],
       [2, 5]])
```

Comment: My first reading was that OP wants arbitrary striding rather than a plain reshape; but this may infact be what he is looking for.

Comment: @EelcoHoogendoorn: This actually does give him arbitrary striding; replace `3` with any other N that's a divisor of `6` (that is, `1` or `2`) and you get an N x (6/N) array that's the equivalent of `np.array([[a[i::z] for i in range(z)])`.

Comment: which is a divisor of 6; so not arbitrary.